# Can't change neo4j database location

Tags: powershell, neo4j

Neo4j version: Community Edition 2.3.2
Starting neo4j ce 2.3.2 by provided visual tool works correct while using a custom DB directory.

For example:

- database location: `C:\Neo4jDB`
- database tuning file: `C:\Neo4jDB\neo4j.properties`
- server configuration file: `C:\Users\leo\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community Edition\neo4j-server.properties`
  here I set: `org.neo4j.server.database.location="C:/Neo4jDB"`

Starting neo4j ce 2.3.2 by Windows PowerShell works correct ONLY if I use default configuration (`data/graph.db`), but if I change `C:\Neo4j\conf\neo4j-server.properties` file setting to

```
org.neo4j.server.database.location="C:/Neo4jDB"
```

(like while using provided visual tool) Windows PowerShell rises the following error:

```
Start-Service : Service 'Neo4JLEO (Neo4JLEO)' cannot be started due to the
following error: Cannot start service Neo4JLEO on computer '.'.
At C:\neo4j\bin\Neo4j-Management\Start-Neo4jServer.ps1:142 char:30
+       $result = Start-Service <<<<  -Name $ServiceName -PassThru
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses back-slashes as path delimiters. Try replacing the forward-slash in your configuration with back-slash.

I.e. `org.neo4j.server.database.location="C:\Neo4jDB"`

Comment: As I've said the "/" works ok using visual tool. So I expect it works ok in other cases. I'd like to know if community edition has some limitations in order to change settings startine from windows powershell.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say anything about limitations for windows powershell: http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.2/powershell.html

Comment: Unfortunatelly. So we need to understand why it doesn't work. Has any body experienced the behaviour I had? I've already tried another suggestion about using shortcuts to redirect default, or configured by visual tool, db directory, but neo4j seems to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually previous answer is partially correct. Windows uses "\", but the neo4j.conf file should have "c:\\Neo4jDB" (double slash) in it. That is what I am using, this way the service is able to start. 
It has nothing to do with powershell limitations, the manually starting it from services.msg will present same error. It has more to do with service vs application (what you call visual tool).